# How to open newly split PDF file in Mac Preview using PyPDF2?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

In the following code, I am extracting several pages from a PDF file. What I want is for my laptop to open the newly created PDF file (in this case "NewPDF.pdf) the way my computer would usually open a PDF file (in my case with "Preview") after executing the code.
How would I go about that?

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

pdf_file = 'Paper.pdf'
pdf = PdfReader(pdf_file)

pdfwriter = PdfWriter()

for page_num in range(1,9):
    pdfwriter.add_page(pdf.pages[page_num])

from pathlib import Path
with Path("NewPDF.pdf").open(mode="wb") as output_file:
    pdfwriter.write(output_file)

print('Your PDF file has been successfully split.')
```

I tried to use the open() and PdfReader function, but I don't think I fully understand what they do yet.

Thank you very much. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: import os 
os.startfile("NewPDF.pdf") // Open the newly created PDF file with the default PDF viewer

Comment: @Akash Thank you, that was very helpful! It didn't work for me initially because I'm using a Mac, but os.system("open NewPDF.pdf") worked. So thank you!

Answer (score -1):

you can use the [subprocess docs][1]https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html module in Python.

```
# open the new PDF file using the default application on your computer(in Windows)
subprocess.run(['start', 'NewPDF.pdf'], shell=True)
```

the function is used to run the open command on the new PDF file. I hope it will help you.